# Rails Admin gem installed properly but missing the admin folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

As the title explains I've added the **rails_admin gem** but it's missing the **app/admin** folder with the admin configurations. But the app is integrated and works fine with the gem: I've added resources on the gem and on the admin site is configured and displayed properly.

I have used Rails Admin before but I didn't have such problem. And based on their documentation after you run the installer: `..as well as a new folder at app/admin to put all your admin configurations.` so it should be pretty much there right away.

Anyone encountered similar problem or know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails Admin is mounted as a rails engine, so when you execute the task as described in the doc, it will creates some migrations (that you later have to run with **rake db:migrate**) and mount the routes as an engine.

However, [**activeadmin**](http://activeadmin.info/) is a gem that allows you to do more customization in the admin, and that actually creates the **app/admin** files in order to customize each one of the models on your admin.

Update your Gemfile, remove the line

```
gem 'rails_admin'
```

And add the line

```
gem 'activeadmin'
```

Make sure to remove the initialization file created by railsadmin, and the migrations created by railsadmin, as well as the mounting root that rails admin introduced into your **config/routes.rb**, follow the documentation on activeadmin and you should be able to see and update the admin files you are looking for :)

Comment: I've done that when I first installed the gem but no it doesn't do the job. What it does, is configuring the gem with devise and an Admin resource I created and asks me "Where do you want to mount rails_admin? Press <enter> for [admin]"

Comment: I have the initialization file and that's why it's weird I don't have the app/admin folder

Comment: That's the same reason I got confused about your question, **rails_admin** doesn't create **app/admin** folder, **rails_admin** is a rails engine. The gem **active_admin** (https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) is the one that creates the **app/admin** folder.

Comment: my god you are right, I just realized :) I forgot that i used to use the active_admin before, i thought it was rails_admin

Comment: I'll apreciate if you select my answer as accepted and a positive vote :)

Comment: Hi rorra. I would like to do that but as of now the question is very misleading and confusing. I think what is best to do is for you to edit the answer with a "Hey mister you are talking about the wrong gem kind of thing" so that is clear to the everyone that might have a look at the question. Keep the rails admin information as well.

Comment: Done :) I updated the answer, now is clear to others as well.